# Update counter field when a new record inserted on another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables and I want to update a counter-record field Table A when a new record inserted or deleted on table B and the code is the same.

Table A Fields

ID-CODE-COUNTER-etc..

Table B Fields

ID-CODE-etc..

When a new record inserted/deleted on Table B I want to count-it on Table A COUNTER FIELD if they have the same CODE field.

I suppose this can be done with trigger but I need some help on this.

Comment: if you follow strict normalization rules you shouldn't be storing calculated values within a table but generate the counter column within a view..

Answer (score 1):

We could probably be achieved using MySQL triggers.

We should consider the option of *not* storing a counter on `table_a`, and instead just getting a count from `table_b`.

There's are also some concerns we need to be aware of in implementing triggers. There's a potential performance impact, and for triggers performing DML, there's a potential for introducing lock contention. Triggers aren't free, and they are not a "magic bullet".

We need an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger (to handle cases where a row is updated to change the value of the `code` column), as well as `AFTER INSERT` and `AFTER DELETE` triggers.

We are going to want a suitable index available on table_b, e.g.

```
 ON table_a (code)
```

Assuming that table_a `counter` column is NOT NULL, and that `counter` is initialized to the value we expect.

As a first cut:

-- after delete

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER table_b_ad
AFTER DELETE ON table_b
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- decrement counter on row of table_a with matching OLD code
    UPDATE table_a a
       SET a.counter = a.counter - 1
     WHERE a.code <=> OLD.code
    ;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

-- after insert

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER table_b_ai
AFTER INSERT ON table_b
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- increment counter on row of table_a with matching NEW code
    UPDATE table_a a
       SET a.counter = a.counter + 1
     WHERE a.code <=> NEW.code
    ;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

-- after update

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER table_b_au
AFTER UPDATE ON table_b
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NOT ( NEW.code <=> OLD.code ) THEN
       -- decrement counter on row of table_a that matches OLD code
       UPDATE table_a a
          SET a.counter = a.counter - 1
        WHERE a.code <=> OLD.code
       ;
       -- increment counter on row of table_a that matches NEW code
       UPDATE table_a a
          SET a.counter = a.counter + 1
        WHERE a.code <=> NEW.code
       ;
    END IF; 
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Note:

Within a MySQL trigger,

`NEW.code` refers to the "new" value assigned to column `code` by an INSERT or UPDATE statement.

`OLD.code` refers to the "old" value that was in the column `code` before a UPDATE or DELETE statement.

`<=>` (spaceship operator) is NULL-safe comparison operator, returns either TRUE or FALSE. Does not return NULL like the regular comparison operator does when comparing a NULL value.

`x <=> y` is short hand equivalent to writing `( x = y OR ( x IS NULL AND y IS NULL ) )`

The purpose for doing the comparison in the UPDATE trigger is that if the value of `code` didn't change, there's no need to go through the rigmarole of subtracting 1 from the count for that `code` value, and then immediately adding 1 back to that same count. It's more efficient just to avoid running the unnecessary UPDATE statements.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @spencer7593, one more question what the meaning of OLD.code and New.code, there are different fields or something else ?

Comment: `NEW.` and `OLD.` are special qualifiers in MySQL triggers.  `NEW.col` references the "new" value assigned to col in the row being inserted or updated, `OLD.col` references the value of the existing "old" value in the row being updated or deleted. (`NEW.` can be used in INSERT and UPDATE triggers, `OLD.` can be used in UPDATE and DELETE triggers.)